# Flutter - type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a list of document id that I wanted to update. But when I use the list the error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'` happens.

My firebase code:

```
Future createGroupChat(
      String groupName, String userName, memberList, memberIDList) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('username', isEqualTo: memberList)
        .snapshots();

    DocumentReference groupDocRef = await groupCollection.add({
      'groupName': groupName,
      'admin': [userName],
      'members': memberList,
      'groupID': '',
    });

    groupDocRef.update({
      'groupID': groupDocRef.id,
      'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userName])
    });

    DocumentReference userDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID);
    userDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });


    DocumentReference memberDocRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(memberIDList);
    return memberDocRef.update({
      'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
    });
    
  }
```

My onPressed code to trigger `createGroupChat`:

```
onPressed: () {
          if (groupNameController != null) {
            DatabaseMethods(userID: user.uid).createGroupChat(
                groupNameController.text,
                Constants.myName,
                selectedUsers,
                memberIDList);
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroupChatPage()));
          } 
        },
```

I've tried @Sal Man's suggestion by passing index to memberIDList[index] using a for loop as below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < memberIDList.length; i++) {
      DocumentReference memberDocRef =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(memberIDList[i]);
      memberDocRef.update({
        'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
      });
      */
      return print(memberIDList[i]);
    }
```

But the for loop only iterates once even if I have three variables in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Add index to `membberIDList`

```
   Future<void> updateMethod({int index}){
        DocumentReference memberDocRef =
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc(memberIDList[index]);
            return await memberDocRef.update({
              'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id.toString() + '_' + groupName])
            });

}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the line of error. The error is at the ```doc(memberIDList)```.

Comment: what is the value of `memberIDLis` ?

Comment: memberIDLis should be a string not a list , if you want to use different document every time you have to pass an index to `memberIDLis[index]`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to apply what you had mentioned above.

Comment: Probably you want to use this function inside a listview.builder where you have index for each item from firebase , you could put index as a parameter for your function then when you want to use the function inside the listview just pass the index

Comment: This function should be triggered by an onPressed event. I don't think I can apply this part of the function inside a listview.builder.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion using a for loop. The code is updated above.

Answer (score 0):

memberIDList is of type List, doc method signature takes a String as a parameter. Try to pass an element of memberIDList which is of type String instead of passing the entire List as an argument.

If you want to get data for all elements of memberIDList, an option is to use Future.forEach method.

```
Future getDataByUserId(String userId) {
  DocumentReference memberDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc(userId);
 
  return memberDocRef.update({
    'groups': FieldValue.arrayUnion([groupDocRef.id + '_' + groupName])
  });
}


Future.wait(memberIDList.map(getDataByUserId)).then((List responses) => ... );
```

Comment: I had added more part of my code for better understanding.

Comment: can you post the error stack trace please ?

Comment: you still pass a List instead of a String as a parameter, is there a specific reason for it ?

Comment: memberIDList is a list of ids that is selected by the user to be added into a group. And I still couldn't figure how to break it into a single element and run it based on how many elements in the list.

Comment: did you try to call Future.wait as I show in my answer ? it allows you to await for multiple futures to resolve.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but it seems like it is still not working.